# select tag not passing value to PHP code

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, tags

I have 2 PHP files.

File1: A form to select skills from an existing table (Skills table with column name: `skill` & `skill_id`)

```
<select name="skill1">
                                <?php 
                                    $self=$_SESSION['subuser_id'];
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM skills";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                                            {
                                                $skill = $row["skill"];
                                                $skill_id= $row["skill_id"]; 
                                                ?>
                                                <option value='<?php $skill_id?>'><?php echo $skill;?></option>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                ?>
                            </select>
```

File2: I am recalling value through `$skill1 =$_POST['skill1'];` which is returning null.

I want to pass `skill_id` of the selected `skill` in code 1 to `$skill1` variable on file2

Comment: `<?php echo $skill_id?>`

Comment: without a `<form>` statement, this code does nothing.

Comment: This returns skill_id from a pre-existing table. What's the problem with this ?

Comment: <form> is there at the start of the page and let me assure you that the form is submitted.

Comment: Once again `<?php echo $skill_id?>`

Comment: Sorry Zigsaw saying 'let me assure you' doesn't mean anything to coders.  copy the line that contains the `<form>`. That's an important piece to how the data is formatted to the next call

Comment: @u_mulder means that you have ommited to echo the variable in option value so it is empty.

Comment: Thank you @KostasMitsarakis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 <option value='<?php $skill_id?>'><?php echo $skill;?></option>
```

to

```
<option value='<?php ECHO $skill_id;?>'><?php echo $skill;?></o
```

Comment: Thanks ... Resolved !!
I am new at stack overflow and this is amazing